# Distribution given Poisson and Exponential

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Suppose buses arrive at a bus stop at a rate of $\lambda$ buses per hour. One bus, independent of the other buses, arrives, and will stay there for an Expo($\lambda$$_2$) number of hours. Find the distribution of the number of other buses that arrive while  this bus is at the station.

I'm having issues trying to get the two together and making a distribution from there (using the Gamma distribution specifically). You know that a poisson process is a series of exponentials, but then how do you use this specific story to calculate the distribution? Can someone walk me through this?

Comment: Conditioning on the staying time of this bus $T = t$, the number of arrivals before it leaves $N \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$. So you got the conditional pmf, and you can obtain the unconditional one by law of total probability:
$\displaystyle \Pr\{N = n\} = \int_0^{+\infty} \Pr\{N = n|T = t\}f_T(t)dt$

Comment: @BGM So, for the conditional PMF, you just have to plug in $/lambda$t into the poisson distribution, correct?

Comment: Yes at that should be almost the very first thing you learn when you touch this Poisson process topic.